# nginx fails routing when slash is at the end

Tags: nginx

The following nginx config serves `http://alpha.mydomain/mypath/test` fine, however fails on `http://alpha.mydomain/mypath/test/` with 500 Internal Server Error. Notice the slash in the end of the second URL.

The app is HTML5 application therefore the intent is to serve index.html for all /mypath/ paths and let the client side handle the logic.

```
server {
listen *:80;
server_name alpha.mydomain.com beta.mydomain.com;

location ~ ^/mypath/.*$ {
    default_type text/html; # fix for octet stream coming back sometimes
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject-web/index.html;
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
}

location / {
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject-web/;
}

}
```

Comment: Exactly how does it "fail"?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What's in nginx's error log, then?

Comment: "/home/ubuntu/myproject-web/index.htmlindex.html" is not a directory

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a fix per se, but you can work around this issue by adding the following line to your config:

```
rewrite (.*)/$  $1;
```